# consultar total, agrupar por rut y validar los que no cumplen con la condicion

Tags: php, mysql

hace un rato que estoy tratando de solucionar un tema y de verdad no he logrado hacerlo.

les cuento: necesito consultar cuantos registros tiene una tabla agrupado por rut, entonces si alguno de los grupos es distinto que me pueda almacenar o mostrar el registro faltante

si consulto por grupo me debiera mostrar

```
3 (rut terminado en 4)
2 (rut terminado en 9)
```

pero al hacer la consulta me da como resultado 2.

```
$cons_pag = "SELECT COUNT(*) total  FROM tbl_ingresos where motivo='Mensualidad' group by rut";
    $result = mysql_query($cons_pag, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $fila['total']."<br>";
```

si me pueden ayudar, se los agradeceria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues si el RUT que termina en 9 es el mismo siempre y el que termina en 4 es el mismo siempre, hay dos registros en el resultado y sólo estás leyendo uno.

Comment: si te das cuenta, el que termina en 4 son 3 registros.

Comment: Si te das cuenta, tu misma pregunta dice que el resultado tiene DOS filas, [3,2]. Estás leyendo UNA (y te está mostrando el 2). Tienes que recorrer el resultado de la consulta